# Can not get html content with javascript is disable with message "Please enable JavaScript to view the page content."

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm using node to get content of html page from url. Here is my code:

```
request({
url     : url,
gzip    : true,
timeout : 2000
}, function(error, response, html){
   console.log(html); 
});
```

But some of url when I run it appear message "Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.". I'm try google a lot of thing but still not yet work. How can I fix it?

ex url: http://www.barnesandnoble.com/blog/this-weeks-biggest-books/

Comment: try visiting that page with javascript disabled in your browser - that's how node will get the page

Comment: @JaromandaX It's is a blank page with message "Please enable JavaScript to view the page content."

Comment: exactly, so your scraping is doing what it should

Answer (score 0):

Node.js scraping currently does not process Javascript and so you can only retrieve javascript-less data, such as JSON objects from APIs and such. Hope that clears things up!

Comment: Can someone please tell me why this was downvoted? I ask because I want to learn.